# create a responsive grid where the elements occupy the available space to be located according to their size

Tags: css

With this code, I get the following result:

[image]

I want to know how I can make the `container > divs` fit into the available space, just like in this image:

[image]

how can I do it?

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  border:3px solid black;
}

.container > div{
  margin:5px 15px;
}

.son1{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}

.son2{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:250px;
  height:220px;
}

.son3{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:200px;
  height:270px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="son1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cum totam voluptates, molestias aliquid quod, placeat harum inventore assumenda sed itaque perferendis eligendi tempore ullam, incidunt qui. Hic, recusandae, iste.
  
  </div>
  <div class="son2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam porro, aperiam facilis, optio illum molestiae. Doloribus, dolores numquam voluptatum at quae ducimus pariatur! Esse ullam facere aperiam veniam error tempora!
  </div>
  <div class="son3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, dicta porro quia. Sed error nulla ratione temporibus, blanditiis aspernatur suscipit ipsum, odit expedita libero hic, asperiores eveniet adipisci quisquam labore!
  </div>
  
  <div class="son3">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, dicta porro quia. Sed error nulla ratione temporibus, blanditiis aspernatur suscipit ipsum, odit expedita libero hic, asperiores eveniet adipisci quisquam labore!
  </div>
  
</div>
```

NOTE: this is my real problem, with this example I know that I can solve my problem

[image]

Comment: That seems like a really weird expected layout. Sure you want that?

Comment: @connexo this is my real problem https://i.imgur.com/5YNkUC6.jpg

Comment: only float can approximate this: https://jsfiddle.net/smvhk0gt/1/ (yes float ..) .. you will have not luck with Flexbox or CSS grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a grid system for you. Will it solve your problem? please take a look and let me know.

Note that I didn't work on the responsive side of this snippet. Also, there is an overflow and I am sure you can fix that easily.

And here is a screenshot of the result. Is this what you are looking for?

[image: Result]

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
  font: 80% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 177px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat( 4, 180px);
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  color: black;
}

.a {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background-color: #444;
}

.c {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background-color: beige;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 3 / 6;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

.e {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: burlywood;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 4 / 4;
  align-self: stretch;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">
    <p>This is box A. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! Excepturi, minus dolorum? Sapiente nam facere veniam. Nesciunt?</p>

  </div>
  <div class="box b">
    <p>This is box B.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! </p>

  </div>
  <div class="box c">
    <p>This is box C.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! Excepturi, minus dolorum? Sapiente nam facere veniam. Nesciunt?</p>

  </div>
  <div class="box d">
    <p>This is box D.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! Excepturi, minus dolorum? Sapiente nam facere veniam. Nesciunt?</p>

  </div>
  <div class="box e">
    <p>This is box E</p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni fugiat commodi, at quia atque sequi, libero tempora repellendus perferendis, quam aliquam. Itaque minima at, perferendis fugit vitae impedit facere possimus.
    </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! Excepturi, minus dolorum? Sapiente nam facere veniam. Nesciunt?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus accusamus necessitatibus cumque fugit odit ducimus eveniet laboriosam amet veritatis impedit, sint explicabo! Excepturi, minus dolorum? Sapiente nam facere veniam. Nesciunt?</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for more customized gird I highly recommend using this library it will help you out a lot: [Cascading grid layout library](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

The Github repo for [masonry](https://github.com/desandro/masonry)

I hope that helps you out reaching an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want irregular sized containers to line up probably best to use floats or Masonry (jQuery plugin).

But flexbox is great if you want to align columns very specifically and have them line up really evenly. I've removed all heights and added flex-wrap: wrap and align-content: flex-start to the container class to make this work.

You can take this and add spacing you desire, I put in the box model in css so padding won't shift the containers/increase their percentage widths.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-content: flex-start;

  border:3px solid black;
}

.container > div{

}

.son1{
  border:1px solid red;
  width: 60%;
}

.son2{
  border:1px solid blue;
  width: 40%;
}

.son3{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="son1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum cum totam voluptates, molestias aliquid quod, placeat harum inventore assumenda sed itaque perferendis eligendi tempore ullam, incidunt qui. Hic, recusandae, iste.
  
  </div>
  <div class="son2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam porro, aperiam facilis, optio illum molestiae. Doloribus, dolores numquam voluptatum at quae ducimus pariatur! Esse ullam facere aperiam veniam error tempora!
  </div>
  <div class="son1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, dicta porro quia. Sed error nulla ratione temporibus, blanditiis aspernatur suscipit ipsum, odit expedita libero hic, asperiores eveniet adipisci quisquam labore!
  </div>
  
  <div class="son2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores, dicta porro quia. Sed error nulla ratione temporibus, blanditiis aspernatur suscipit ipsum, odit expedita libero hic, asperiores eveniet adipisci quisquam labore!
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your time, but I have a dynamic size container in my real code, so it doesn't help me to assign a fixed percentage or something like that.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You shouldn't use static widths as it won't be at all responsive and is the cause of your issue.

Comment: my divs have a dynamic height, that's why I need to have a solution to position my divs as in the result image

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a vertical flexbox masonry using CSS only (no JS), you can try this:

```
.masonry { /* Container */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 1000px;
  margin-left: -8px; /* Adjustment for the gutter */
  width: 100%;
}

.masonry-brick {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0; /* Some gutter */
  max-width: 33%; /* 3 columns */
}
```

```css
.masonry { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 1000px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  width: 100%;
}

.masonry-brick {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  max-width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="masonry">

<div class="masonry-brick">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. Sed ut sagittis purus. Suspendisse sed scelerisque lorem, sed rutrum dui. Morbi elementum aliquam ante, eget malesuada tortor mattis sed. Sed sit amet porta mauris. Sed sed sollicitudin lorem, non finibus leo. Vivamus sapien dui, bibendum at nibh nec, consectetur ornare justo. Sed ac augue id libero porttitor placerat. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. 
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Cras ac justo consectetur, fringilla tortor ac, tristique massa. Sed ultricies pretium nisi ac sollicitudin. Pellentesque viverra eros id blandit consequat. In turpis nulla, sodales ac tristique nec, volutpat quis felis. Curabitur mi quam, euismod sit amet egestas faucibus, rhoncus ac massa. Maecenas ac fringilla elit, quis eleifend ligula. Sed laoreet est ut dolor dictum, et feugiat leo ullamcorper. Phasellus ligula neque, finibus aliquam fermentum eget, lobortis at sem. Integer vulputate eu mauris eu ullamcorper.
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. Sed ut sagittis purus. Suspendisse sed scelerisque lorem, sed rutrum dui. Morbi elementum aliquam ante, eget malesuada tortor mattis sed. Sed sit amet porta mauris. Sed sed sollicitudin lorem, non finibus leo. Vivamus sapien dui, bibendum at nibh nec, consectetur ornare justo. Sed ac augue id libero porttitor placerat. 
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. Sed ut sagittis purus. Suspendisse sed scelerisque lorem, sed rutrum dui. Morbi elementum aliquam ante, eget malesuada tortor mattis sed. Sed sit amet porta mauris. Sed sed sollicitudin lorem, non finibus leo. Vivamus sapien dui, bibendum at nibh nec, consectetur ornare justo. Sed ac augue id libero porttitor placerat. 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. Sed ut sagittis purus. Suspendisse sed scelerisque lorem, sed rutrum dui. Morbi elementum aliquam ante, eget malesuada tortor mattis sed. Sed sit amet porta mauris. Sed sed sollicitudin lorem, non finibus leo. Vivamus sapien dui, bibendum at nibh nec, consectetur ornare justo. Sed ac augue id libero porttitor placerat. 
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Cras ac justo consectetur, fringilla tortor ac, tristique massa. Sed ultricies pretium nisi ac sollicitudin. Pellentesque viverra eros id blandit consequat. In turpis nulla, sodales ac tristique nec, volutpat quis felis. Curabitur mi quam, euismod sit amet egestas faucibus, rhoncus ac massa. Maecenas ac fringilla elit, quis eleifend ligula. Sed laoreet est ut dolor dictum, et feugiat leo ullamcorper. Phasellus ligula neque, finibus aliquam fermentum eget, lobortis at sem. Integer vulputate eu mauris eu ullamcorper. Curabitur porta nibh nec metus scelerisque, eu ultricies augue viverra. Nam laoreet, libero vitae molestie condimentum, justo lorem vestibulum erat, sit amet elementum risus augue at erat.
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam mi massa, tristique vehicula ligula at, vulputate vulputate tortor. Etiam lobortis ex eu nunc tristique, in tristique quam placerat. Nullam in tempor felis. Fusce congue pretium urna, cursus suscipit dolor rutrum in. Sed ut sagittis purus. Suspendisse sed scelerisque lorem, sed rutrum dui. Morbi elementum aliquam ante, eget malesuada tortor mattis sed. Sed sit amet porta mauris.
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Sed non euismod tellus. Mauris rhoncus nulla id eros blandit, facilisis gravida ex congue. Aliquam ullamcorper tristique enim, eget suscipit velit. Praesent non eros id diam molestie lacinia sed quis diam. Pellentesque semper sapien blandit risus consequat, nec tempus eros ultrices. Duis ornare magna posuere massa sollicitudin posuere vitae a mauris. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.  
</div>

<div class="masonry-brick">
Cras ac justo consectetur, fringilla tortor ac, tristique massa. Sed ultricies pretium nisi ac sollicitudin. Pellentesque viverra eros id blandit consequat. In turpis nulla, sodales ac tristique nec, volutpat quis felis. Curabitur mi quam, euismod sit amet egestas faucibus, rhoncus ac massa. Maecenas ac fringilla elit, quis eleifend ligula. Sed laoreet est ut dolor dictum, et feugiat leo ullamcorper. Phasellus ligula neque, finibus aliquam fermentum eget, lobortis at sem. Integer vulputate eu mauris eu ullamcorper.
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: can you please put it in a snippet to see it working?

Comment: I appreciate you too much, but in my code it doesn't work.

Comment: that is, I should not specify the number of columns. this should be dynamic. I want my divs to fit into the available space

Comment: Then you should use grid, not flex.